# Create new table from selection then union

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two table T1

```
Date   Symbol   high   low  close 
xxx     yyy      1.2    1.0   1.14
```

and table T2

```
Date   Symbol   factor
xxx     yyy      1.2
```

I want to create a new table from T1 that only with three fields

```
Date   Symbol   new_close
xxx     yyy      1.4
```

Where new_close=iff(date and symbol match for T1 and T2, close*factor, close).
Here is my code:

```
Select a.Tdate, a.Symbol , a.close*(b.factor as fixP
Into ctsWithSplit
From cts a inner join split b
Where a.Tdate=b.Tdate and a.Symbol=b.Symbol
Union
Select Tdate,Symbol,close
From cts
Where not in ctsWithSplit
```

I feel like there must be a easy way to do it? How to fix it please?

Comment: Why are you using `into` with Oracle?  The syntax for a new table in Oracle is `create table as`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a `left join` and `create table as`:

```
create table ctsWithSplit as
    select c.Tdate, c.Symbol,
           c.close * coalesce(s.factor, 1) as new_close
    from cts c left join
         splits s
         on c.Tdate = s.Tdate and c.symbol = s.symbol;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What if I want to subtract from factor other than *, can I still use coalesce() function please?

Comment: I should use c.close-coalesce(s.factor,0), is that right please

Comment: Your question says multiply, but if you want to subtract, then I would use "0" rather than "1".